# Esqueleto count inside select

Tags: sql, haskell, yesod, esqueleto

I have the following `Entities`:

```
Group
  name Text

GroupUser
  user UserId
  group GroupId
```

and I would like to do a query like this:

```
select g.* /* Everything from g */
     , count(gu.id) groupUsersCount 
  from Group g
  left outer join GroupUser gu on gu.groupId = g.id
group by g.id
```

Can it be done with `Esqueleto`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**esqueleto docs for `groupBy`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-2.4.3/docs/Database-Esqueleto.html#v:groupBy) contain good examples of how to use it.

Moreover, by reading through the [**Getting Started**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-2.4.3/docs/Database-Esqueleto.html#g:3) section, you'll see several example of queries including the equivalent of `table.*`:

```
do people <- select $
             from $ \person -> do
             return person
```

Putting the two together means something like this should work:

```
select $ from \(g `LeftOuterJoin` gh) -> do
  on (gu ^. GroupId ==. g ^. Id)
  groupBy (g ^. Id)
  return (g, countRows)
```